# Why must a variable be assigned before a for loop

Tags: c#, variables

The following code produces a "Use of unassigned local variable 'foo'" error. It is easy to fix by replacing `double foo;` with `var foo = 0d;` but I would like to understand, why the compiler (Visual Studio) complains. In my opinion, there is no way `var bar = foo;` can be reached without assigning `foo` in the for loop.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double foo;
            for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                foo = 1.23;
            }
            var bar = foo;
        }
    }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think the compiler recognizes that your for loop loops at least once.

Comment: The compiler would have to evaluate the loop params to be sure that the loop is even entered. - Btw: Imo: even declaring an unassigned variable is bad practice.

Comment: Because static analysis only goes to a certain point. And seemingly, interpreting loop conditions is beyond that point. It may be really simple in this case, but what if the lower and upper limit are not some constant but calculated from some input values? The compiler would have no way of ensuring that the loop's body was executed at least once. So it acts on the premise "better safe than sorry"

Comment: @derpirscher don't forget that one must evaluate body of the for loop too, possibly for all iterations. I.e. if one decided to add `break` before the assignment or put assingment into `if` conditions...

Comment: @derpirscher and Alexei: You are right, it could get very complex, especially when the conditions are not constants. So, the answer is simply "better safe than sorry".

Answer (score 1):

This error is generated when the compiler encounters a construct that might result in the use of an unassigned variable, even if your particular code does not. This avoids the necessity of overly complex rules for definite assignment.

[Here is more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165#:%7E:text=The%20C%23%20compiler%20doesn%27t%20allow%20the%20use%20of%20uninitialized%20variables.&text=This%20error%20is%20generated%20when,complex%20rules%20for%20definite%20assignment).

Answer (score 0):

Loop parameters are usually evaluated at runtime, so the compiler has no way of knowing the condition of your loop. Because it's obviously possible for a for loop not to run at all (if the condition is initially false), the compiler warns you with an error about the potential use of an unassigned variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler can't be sure whether `foo` will be assigned in the loop. Maybe in your case it's possible to infer, but the compiler just doesn't support that. Also it's bad practice in C# to declare variable without initial value.